# Should i create seperate page for every ad for search engine indexing purposes in my website

Tags: web-hosting, web-crawlers, web-applications, web-services, website-promotion

I am going to create a simple ad marketing web site. so I should use databases  as my storing method. Now my question is If  I want to show my  customers ads in Google search result page(just like Freelancer etc when we search freelancer Google shows us some jobs posted by others)  should I create seperate page that contain customer details for every ad that post by my customers? that's mean this page is only for search engine indexing. other All functionality performing by dynamic page.( I know my English is little bad please explain this to me)

Comment: Sorry but the question is too site specific, a little unclear and opinionated. Please visit our help centre for further assistance as you most likely can save your question with a quality edit.